# Please assist with this if statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The if statement in this googlescript code should return certain values for each condition, but it does not function properly. I tried 'else if' also, but keep  getting error messages. I am a beginner and would like some feedback.

```
function doGet() {



 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1;         // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 10000;     // Number of total rows
  var startColumn = 1
  var numColumns = 17



// Fetch the range of cells A2:Q10001
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var timeStamp = row[0];
    var purchaseDate = row[1];
    var month = row[2];
    var responsibleParty = row[3];
    var invoiceTo = row[4];
    var item = row[5];
    var ifOther = row[6]
    var category = row[7];
    var amount = row[8];
    var split = row[9];
    var comments = row[10];
    var splitOptions = row[11];
    var splitCalc = row[12];
    var costToResponsible = row[13];
    var costToOther = row[14];
    var emailSent = row[15];
    var totalBudget = row[16];

    var fiftyFifty = "BQ:SQ, 50:50";
    if (split === fiftyFifty);
    var calc2 = amount*.5;
    {sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 14).setValue(calc2);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); }

    var sixtyForty = "BQ:SQ, 60:40";
    if (split === sixtyForty);
    var calc3 = amount*.33;
    {sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 14).setValue(calc3);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); }

    var fortySixty = "BQ:SQ; 40:60";
    if (split === fortySixty);
    var calc1 = amount*.67;
    {sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 14).setValue(calc1);
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();}

    var Bqpays = "BQ pays total amt";
    var calc4 = "0";
    if (split === Bqpays);
    {sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 14).setValue(calc4);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); }

    var Sqpays = "SQ pays total amt";
    var calc5 = amount;
    if (split === Sqpays) 
    {sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 14).setValue(calc5);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); }
```

Comment: Please describe your problem properly. See [ask] and [mcve] for guidance. If you are getting errors, then you should include them in your question.

Comment: `if (split === fiftyFifty);` does nothing, drop the semicolon

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this part?

```
if (split === Bqpays);
    {sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 14).setValue(calc4);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); }
```

You don't need a semicolon after `if();`

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong syntax, remove the semicolon after the if block

```
  if (split === sixtyForty);
```

Should be

```
if (split === sixtyForty){
 var calc3 = amount*.33;
 etc....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have semicolon's after the conditional statement. That terminates the expression.

```
if (split === fiftyFifty){
    var calc2 = amount*.5;
    sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 14).setValue(calc2);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
}
```

That's the correct syntax for an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

your if/else statement in Javascript must look like

```
if (condition) {

    block of code to be executed if the condition is true
}
```

Or if you wanted to use else you do this :

```
if (condition) {
    block of code to be executed if the condition is true
} else { 
    block of code to be executed if the condition is false
}
```